# Cloudfoundry v2 links redirect to old v1 url

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I moved my grails site from cloudfoundry v1 to v2 host, all looks perfect until i started to click in my links.

In cloudfoundry v1 i had the url adress http://controlealunos.cloudfoundry.com/ and in v2 i have http://controlealunos.cfapps.io/.

You can see the error happening when you click in login button. It's been redirec to http://controlealunos.cloudfoundry.com/login/auth?login_error=1, but if i access http://controlealunos.cfapps.io/login/auth?login_error=1 it´s there.

Inside the application i'm suffering the same kind of error. Somebody know what's happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you update your `grails.serverURL` to the http://controlealunos.cfapps.io/

```
environments {
  development {
          ...
  }
  //assuming you're deploying a prod build
  production {
    grails.serverURL = "http://controlealunos.cfapps.io/"
  }
}
```

Comment: you should remove that altogether in later versions of grails since it will work it out based on your request.